# Nginx: 413 entity too large - file does not reach the application

Tags: python-2.7, nginx, wsgi, uwsgi

I'm using `Nginx` and `uwsgi` with wsgi app. When I try to upload the image sometimes the application does not get the image and there used to be error `413 entity too large`.

I fixed this issue by adding `client_max_body_size 4M;`and my `Nginx` conf looks something like:

```
//Add sample Nginx Server
//Block here
```

The error stopped showing but still the file does not reach the application. I don't understand it works on some computers and it dosent work on some.

Comment: I think what you have done is COrrect. But also check your directory permissions and Nginx logs for failure information.

Comment: there are absolutely no errors in the error log I wonder why.. they have permissions as i said it works from some clients and it dosent work from some .. I've tried from almost all the browsers and the results are random and not consistent..

Comment: Can you please add Sample Nginx configuration (mainly Server Block) you are using in your question?

Comment: the server block is  server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:22989;
        client_max_body_size 4M;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;

Answer (score 11):

If you’re getting 413 Request Entity Too Large errors trying to upload, you need to increase the size limit in `nginx.conf` or any other configuration file . Add `client_max_body_size xxM` inside the server section, where `xx` is the size (in megabytes) that you want to allow.

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        client_max_body_size 20M;
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        # Main location
        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It means the max file size is larger than the upload size. See [client_max_body_size](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#client_max_body_size)

So try using instead of using a fixed value.

```
server {
     [...]
     client_max_body_size 0;
     [...]
}
```

A value of 0 will disable the max upload check, I'd recommend putting a fixed value such as **3M**, **10M**, etc... instead though.

Comment: plus 1 For telling how to disable max upload check.

Comment: This parameter can be added to `http` or `server` or `location` context.